# Common Lisp: The fastest way to read the stream

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

folks, what is the fastest approach for reading the stream in Common Lisp (SBCL) ?

For me, that is **read-line**. But suddenly I've stuck with the performance problem with this function - I should read 10kk characters (1000 lines with 10000 chars at each) in 1.5 sec, but read-line failed to achieve it. Is it possible with Common Lisp? Does it provide a C-style **scanf()** function for fast reading?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**. The code:

```
(defun split (string)
  (let ((space-position (position #\Space string)))
    (list 
     (subseq string 0 space-position) 
     (subseq string (+ space-position 1)))))

(defun solve (line)
  (let ((nums (split line))
    (first)
    (second))
    (setq first (parse-integer (car nums)))
    (setq second (parse-integer (cadr nums)))

    (* first second)))

(defun spoj()
  (let ((N (read))
        (line))
    (dotimes (i N)
      (setq line (read-line))
      (format t "~d~%" (solve line))))))

(spoj)
```

Comment: Your bottle neck could very well be what you're doing with the strings _after_ you `read-line` them.  Can you post the code that you're using?

Comment: I'm using SBCL. But it seems you're right. The slow things happens in the code of application logic, after reading the stream.

Actually, I use **parse-integer** and multiplication via long arithmetics. So application reads 1000 pairs of integers (10^4 digits everyone) and prints the result of multiplying of each pair.

Answer (score 4):

Performance for text-oriented I/O can vary quite a lot between implementations, and the strategies that help improve performance on one implementation might not apply to another. What implementation are you using?

Are the lines guaranteed to be the same length?

For what it's worth, I tried your exercise (1,000 lines of 10,000 characters each) and it took about 0.25 seconds to read in SBCL.

Comment: I'm using SBCL. And now I think this is not the I/O issue.

Answer (score 4):

Without profiling it's impossible to tell exactly where your bottlenecks are, but my guess is that `split` and `solve` are slowing you down.  Specifically, when you call `subseq` on the string to split it, you end up allocating two new strings.  Since `parse-integer` can take the start and end indices into the string, there's no need to do the split:

```
(let* ((space-position (position #\Space string))
       (first (parse-integer string :end space-position))
       (second (parse-integer string :start (1+ space-position)))
  (* first second))
```

Comment: PARSE-INTEGER returns a second value of how much of the string it consumed, so you could also use (m-v-b (first end) (parse-integer string :junk-allowed t) (* first (parse-integer string :start (1+ end) :junk-allowed t))) or similar.